# Overwriting a variable initialized with the new keyword c++

Tags: c++, new-operator, delete-operator

If I do something like:

```
void foo() {
  bar* b2 = new bar();
  b2 = new bar();
}
```

What happens to the first bar value initialized with `new`? Is it overwritten by the second assignment, or should it be deleted using the delete keyword beforehand?

Comment: No, the first `bar` instance alive but lost. It is called a "memory leak". All you are doing is making the `b2` pointer point to a new variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `delete` for the first `b2` before assigning a new value to `b2`. The second call will indeed overwrite the value in `b2` (which is the address of the object created in the first `new`).

In other words, your code has a memory leak, because the first `bar` object is "lost".

Answer (score 5):

This is a memory leak. C++ has allocated space for your object and then you lost all references to it, so it's going to sit there for the rest of your programs runtime being useless and space hungry.

That's why in C++ it's generally prefered **not** to use `new`.

```
void foo() {
  bar b2 = bar();
  b2 = bar();
}
```

especially in situations where you only want to use the variable in 1 scope, allocating it on the stack is a much safer choice. Especially in the case of exceptions, the

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
...
delete foo;
```

is unsafe, what if `...` throws an exception? You leak! If you want safety and pointer semantics in C++11

```
unique_ptr<bar> b2;
```

if you really want pointer semantics. Now when all references to `b2` are lost, it'll go delete itself. Note: Cycles still aren't broken and leak.

Comment: You should at least explain the alternative of using smart pointer wrapper classes so people know what you mean when you say 'it is preferred not to use new'.

Answer (score 0):

If you create something with `new` you have to free it with delete, Otherwise memory leak will be there.
To prevent leak you should write:

```
void foo() {
  bar* b2 = new bar();
  delete b2;
  b2 = new bar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first line:

`bar* b2 = new bar()` will allocate `sizeof(bar)` room on free store (and also call the constructor) and give you the address of this unit, say it's 0x123, this means that b2 remembers 0x123.

But now you overwrite your b2 - it now points to a new location given to you by new. This means that you no longer can reach the older memory unit you had been assigned by the first new call.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line has three 'things' to do.

1. define a variable b2 of the type bar*,
2. allocate a bar object on the heap with the new operator
3. assign the result of 2 to the variable defined in 1

With this separation in mind it's obvious that you assign two times a value to one variable. Since you need this variable to delete the object your are lost after overwriting the first assigned value. This is one situation of a "memory leak".

Before you overwrite the variable `b2` you should think about the first instance of the object of the class `bar`. If it's not required anymore, use `delete` to delete the object. If you still need it make a copy of the pointer.